# How can we have a complex basis for a real-valued space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

I have started studied functional analysis few times ago and now I am stuck in a doubt which I think is really trivial, but I cannot still find an answer.

Consider the Hilbert Space $X = L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$.

Then an orthonormal basis is $\big\{\sqrt{2}coskt,\sqrt{2}sinkt \text{ }|\text{ } k \in \mathbb{N} \big\} \text{ } \cup \big\{1\big\} $.

However, also the following is an orthonormal basis which is made of complex functions $\big\{e^{int}\text{ }|\text{ } n \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$. But isn't X a real-valued space? How can it have a complex orthonormal basis?

Comment: You didn't precisely what your $L^2$ space is, but the formula $f(t)\overline{g(t)}$ suggests it is a space of complex-valued functions.

Comment: it's from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Then what's the problem: $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ have the same span over $\mathbb C$ as $\exp(it)$ and $\exp(-it)$ ?